# If $a$ is a real number greater than one and $x$ and $y$ are rationals with $x\leq y$ then $a^x\leq a^y$

Tags: real-analysis

How can I show the next proposition?:

> If $a$ is a real number greater than one and $x$ and $y$ are rationals with $x\leq y$ then $a^x\leq a^y$

Please, I don't know how to proceed, any help would be really appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  Observe that $a^y = a^{y - x}a^x$.  If $a > 1$, what can you conclude about $a^{y - x}$?